# images URL "Geojson-dashboard" framework for Leaflet js

Tags: leaflet, geojson

a question for somebody that used before the **Geojson-dashboard framework** for Leaflet (https://github.com/fulcrumapp/geojson-dashboard):

Is it possible to add the images URL or Hyperlink dynamically? or is it strictly necessary to edit insight of the geojson file (so to create a column for the URLs)?

My goal could be adding a reference to my images directory (local directory) somewhere into the code (app.js) like this :
`<a target='_blank' href='./assets/img/Seismic_lines/"+feature.properties.LineName+".jpg'></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in its app.js, line 458, it has code to show photos but it looks for the full url and creates a link:

```
// Table formatter to make links clickable
function urlFormatter (value, row, index) {
  if (typeof value == "string" && (value.indexOf("http") === 0 || value.indexOf("https") === 0)) {
    return "<a href='"+value+"' target='_blank'>"+value+"</a>";
  }
}
```

You could modify the if condition to check just for a string and a length > 0. Then modify the return to:

`<a target='_blank' href='./assets/img/Seismic_lines/"+value+".jpg'></a>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying Bill. I am a beginner in programming so I got the idea you gave me, instead if after some tests I don't know exactly how to modify the condition to reach my goal...I will still working on it.